# Reading columns from a text file in C

Tags: c

I have a text file with 100 rows and 512 columns, each column is separated by a tab:

```
row1    00  00  20  00  11  00  00  00  00  10
        00  11  00  55  77  00  00  70  21  00
        90  ...
```

I would like to read through each row and store value in each column in an array.

I dont want to use `sscanf` and separate the variables, as it requires creating another 500 variables.
If I use `fgets`, I can get the whole line, but how do I separate columns with spaces and store them in an array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strtok_r`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp), a reentrant version of [`strtok`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok.3.asp), to separate elements of a string into *tokens*. You can call `strtok_r` in a loop, call [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) on each token, and add tokens to the array for the row.

`strtok_r` has a usage pattern that is nearly identical to that of `strtok`, but it has an extra parameter to represent the current state of the tokenizer. Regular `strtok` keeps that state in the static memory, making the function non-re-entrant.

```
const char *term = "\t\n\r "; // word terminators
char str[] = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
char *state; // Invocation state of strtok_r
char *tok = strtok_r(str, term, &state); // First invocation is different
while (tok) {
        printf("%s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok_r(NULL, term, &state); // subsequent invocations call with NULL
}
```

Comment: can you please show me a overview of the code using strtok_r? I cant find enough examples on it. I completely dont understand the difference between strtok() and strtok_r()

Comment: @user1390048 Sure, please take a look.

Comment: I dont want to read the first element (row1), if I put the line     tok = strtok_r(NULL, term, &state); // subsequent invocations call with NU before  printf("%s\n", tok); its printing the last element twice, how do i change the code?

Comment: @user1390048 Your change looks right. I added the line that you added right before the loop, and I got the right output. If you could post your changed code to pastebin.com, I'd take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use a string tokenizer with a tab delimiter. Here is an [example](http://roseindia.net/c-tutorials/c-string-tokenizer.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

you can use strtok

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

and iterate over each word